# sshで繋いだ先でコマンド発行し、その出力を受け取りたい

Tags: ssh, wsl, expect

SSHで接続を行い、接続先でコマンド実行した結果「のみ」を受け取りたいです。

具体的には接続先でpsqlを使用してSQLを発行した結果を受け取りたいと考えています。
（直接psqlで接続することはできない前提になります。）
以下の通り、expectを使用して実現はできましたが、SSHのコマンドなども入ってしまっております。
欲しいのはpsqlの結果のみなので、SSHで繋いだ先で標準出力に出力されたメッセージのみを受け取りたいです。（下記のコードですとresultに設定したい）

```sh
#!/bin/sh

PGPASS="passwod"

SQL="select col1 from hoge limit 1;"
PSQL="psql -h hostname -p 1234 -U admin -c '${SQL}' database"

COMMAND="export PGPASSWORD=${PGPASS}"
COMMAND="${COMMAND};${PSQL}"

result=`expect -c "
  spawn /usr/bin/ssh user@host -i /key.ppk \"${COMMAND}\"
  expect \"Enter passphrase for key*\"
  send \"password\n\"
  interact;"`

echo ${result}
```

環境は「Ubuntu（Bash on Ubuntu on Windows）」になります。
また、シェルにこだわっている訳ではありませんので、他の言語やツールなどがありましたらご紹介頂ければと思います。

Comment: 参考: ["Remotely run script on Unix, get output locally?"](https://superuser.com/q/130443/680903) -- superuser

Comment: expect を使って実現出来ている現状で、どういった点を問題だと感じているのでしょうか？質問からは読み取れなかったので もう少し噛み砕いて書いていただけると回答が付くかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。実行したコマンドのみを受け取りたい旨を追記致しました。これで伝わりますでしょうか？何か情報ありましたらお願い致します。

Comment: SSHがパスワード認証なのは変えられないのでしょうか。

Comment: 変更できません。パスワード認証では無ければそのままsshを投げれたのですが。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

受け取った出力から不要な行を削除するのが良いと思います。

今回のケースでは、

```
$ /bin/sh script.sh
spawn /usr/bin/ssh user@host -i /key.ppk [command]
Enter passphrase for key '/key.ppk':
[result]
```

最初の2行が不要なので、`tail`等のコマンドで最初の2行を取り除けば所望の結果が得られると思います。